# Automation of performance monitoring of mulesoft application

Tags: python, web-scraping, automation, performance-testing, mulesoft

I would like to automate this process of viewing logs in dashboard and typing the information (Total messages sent in a time period, total errors, CPU usage, memory usage), this task is very time consuming at the moment.
The info is gathered from mulesoft anypoint platform. I'm currently thinking of a way to extract all of the data using python webscraping but I don't know how to use it perfectly.

You'll find here a screenshot of the website i'm trying to get the data off of, you can choose to see the logs specific to a certain time and date. My question is, do I start learning python webscrapping or is there another way of doing things that I am just unaware of ?
[Logs website example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG3Ne.png)

Comment: Are you trying to get some kind of dashboard where you can see the CPU usage, number of message etc directly as Number, instead of the Graphs that are available in Anypoint monitoring by default?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get a json response that contains the data I need (Total messages sent in a time period, total errors, CPU usage, memory usage) and I wanna use my data engineering skills to format them however I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to use web scrapping. All services in Anypoint Platform have a REST API. Most of them are documented at https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/. Scrapping may broke with any minor change to the UI. The REST API is stable.

The screenshot seems to be from Anypoint Monitoring. I see in the catalog [Anypoint Monitoring Archive API](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/anypoint-monitoring-archive-api/). I'm not sure if the API for getting Monitoring Dashboards data is documented. You could alternatively use the older [CloudHub Dashboards API](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/console/method/%232180/). It is probably not exactly the same but it will approximate.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I can make calls to the monitoring api and gather the data ? I'm quite new to mulesoft so I didn't know that was possible!

Comment: Yes, though not every API is documented, meaning for that expected to be use by users.